# what is updateColorViewInt()if drawable=null color and how to fix it

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-json

I am making an app when I started my app in emulator like bluestack then it show this logcat and finish it self

```
    02-25 00:32:21.401 850-850/com.tricknearn.app D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-25 00:32:21.601 850-850/com.tricknearn.app D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 70K, 28% free 2690K/3728K, paused 20ms, total 40ms
02-25 00:32:21.651 850-850/com.tricknearn.app I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.065MB for 6720012-byte allocation
02-25 00:32:21.661 850-859/com.tricknearn.app D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 9252K/10292K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
02-25 00:32:21.671 850-853/com.tricknearn.app D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 11% free 9252K/10292K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 0ms
02-25 00:32:22.011 850-850/com.tricknearn.app I/PGA: Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 850, tid = 850
02-25 00:32:22.031 850-850/com.tricknearn.app I/PGA: New SOCKET connection: com.tricknearn.app (pid 850, tid 850)
02-25 00:32:23.261 850-850/com.tricknearn.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

And when I start this app in mobile device it shows logcat :

```
02-25 00:38:10.804 17347-17347/com.tricknearn.app V/PhoneWindow: updateColorViewInt()if drawable=null color=-14057287
```

what does these means and how to fix these. I don't know about that I tried to find this but i did't get usefull information.Need help guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output from your phone is correct. Last message means -> if drawable wasn't set then background have white color (-14057287 == white). In output i see only debug, info, verbose and one warning - you don't get any error. Dalvik send to you info that garbage collector works and your heap are growing. What are your question?

Comment: app crash after showing these logcat message how to fix that

Comment: @Honey There is no more output in logcat?

Comment: I post all the logcart message of emulator but posted only one line from mobile which crash the whole app

Comment: On the phone when you try to lunch app then you get standard dialog with crash message? That log looks good for me. If application crash then there should be  something like exception (red color message) or something from system.err. Did you try restart adb and then try to lunch application and read logs?

Comment: its fixed now that was an exception